# How to customize the notification in Chrome,Firefox,etc.. of the site is playing media

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, browser

I would like to customize the notification of a site is playing media like YouTube's.
[image: Sample notification]
Is it possible to style the notification with custom pictures, colors etc...?

> This doesn't seem to work in Firefox though

Comment: I do not believe this is possible. This appears to be part of the browser window chrome rather than part of the page subject to HTML and CSS changes.

Comment: Then how does it appear on YouTube?